# How to display Double value on edittext- android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am creating an application which takes numerical vales from the edittext, does calculation on them like calculation of discount, change of currency etc and then display them on another edittext.

I am converting values from string to Double and then again displaying it in the screen by converting double to string. I have marked the line where calculation and displaying of values takes place.

My problem is that, nothing is displayed on the edittext and no error is generated in the logcat.

```
public class Calculator extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText carat,list,price,total,discount,converter,discamt,caratrs;
    Button submit;
    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, clear,dot,calc;
    double int_list=0,int_carat=0,int_discount=0,int_converter=0,int_price=0,int_total=0,int_discamt=0,int_pricers=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

       carat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.carat);
        list=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.list);
        price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
        total=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.total);
        discount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.discount);
        converter=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.converter);
        discamt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.discamt);
        caratrs=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.caratrs);

        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        calc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
        clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        dot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dot);



        price.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        total.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        carat.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        list.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        converter.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        discount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        discamt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        caratrs.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        try{
            one.setOnClickListener(this);

            two.setOnClickListener(this);

            three.setOnClickListener(this);

            four.setOnClickListener(this);

            five.setOnClickListener(this);

            six.setOnClickListener(this);

            seven.setOnClickListener(this);

            eight.setOnClickListener(this);

            nine.setOnClickListener(this);

            zero.setOnClickListener(this);


            dot.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }


        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(carat.isFocused())
                {
                    carat.setText("");
                }
                else if(price.isFocused())
                {
                    price.setText("");
                }
                else if(total.isFocused())
                {
                    total.setText("");
                }
                else if(list.isFocused())
                {
                    list.setText("");
                }
                else if(discount.isFocused())
                {
                    discount.setText("");
                }
                else if(converter.isFocused())
                {
                    converter.setText("");
                }
                else if(discamt.isFocused())
                {
                    discamt.setText("");
                }
                else if(caratrs.isFocused())
                {
                    caratrs.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

---------------------------This is where all the calculation takes place including displaying the value on the edittext-----------------------------



    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int_list = Double.parseDouble(list.getText().toString());
                int_carat = Double.parseDouble(carat.getText().toString());
                int_discount = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());
                int_converter = Double.parseDouble(converter.getText().toString());
                int_discamt = Double.parseDouble(discamt.getText().toString());


                int_discamt = (int_list * int_discount) / 100;
                int_price = int_list - int_discamt;
                int_pricers = int_price * int_converter;
                int_total = int_price * int_converter * int_carat;


                price.setText(Double.toString(int_price));
                discamt.setText(Double.toString(int_discamt));
                caratrs.setText(Double.toString(int_pricers));
                total.setText(Double.toString(int_total));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

     }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if(carat.isFocused())
        {
            carat.setText(carat.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText());
        }

        else if(list.isFocused())
        {
            list.setText(list.getText().toString() +((Button)v).getText());
        }
         else if(discount.isFocused())
        {
            discount.setText(discount.getText().toString() +((Button)v).getText());
        }
        else if(converter.isFocused())
        {
            converter.setText(converter.getText().toString() +((Button)v).getText());
        }


    }

}
```

This is what i am getting in logcat

```
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.diamond.traders.Calculator$2.onClick(Calculator.java:176)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-07 18:00:14.918  14299-14299/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Comment: are you sure is fire onclick listener.. Print something in **calc.setOnClickListener** and check

Comment: please validate gettext() value before parsing to double... possibly you are getting empty string which causes this Number format exception

Comment: this is your error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
at com.diamond.traders.Calculator$2.onClick(Calculator.java:176)
-- Calculator.java:176 --
you do need to validate !empty before parseDouble()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put validation for all EditText field.

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String list = list.getText().toString().trim();
                String carat = carat.getText().toString().trim();
                String discount = discount.getText().toString().trim();
                String converter = converter.getText().toString().trim();
                String discamt = discamt.getText().toString().trim();

                if(list.length() > 0 && carat.length() > 0 && discount.length() > 0
                        && converter.length() > 0 && discamt.length() > 0 )
                {
                     try {
                            int_list = Double.parseDouble(list.getText().toString());
                            int_carat = Double.parseDouble(carat.getText().toString());
                            int_discount = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());
                            int_converter = Double.parseDouble(converter.getText().toString());
                            int_discamt = Double.parseDouble(discamt.getText().toString());


                            int_discamt = (int_list * int_discount) / 100;
                            int_price = int_list - int_discamt;
                            int_pricers = int_price * int_converter;
                            int_total = int_price * int_converter * int_carat;


                            price.setText(Double.toString(int_price));
                            discamt.setText(Double.toString(int_discamt));
                            caratrs.setText(Double.toString(int_pricers));
                            total.setText(Double.toString(int_total));
                     }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter all value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            });
```

Comment: found the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`Double.toString()` is not recommended by lint, because it doesn't take into account locale settings. Consider using `String.format(locale, "%f", 123D);`
You can replace `locale` with Locale.US, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
double doubleValue;

edittext.setText(""+doubleValue);

 OR

edittext.setText(String.valueOf(doubleValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
......
 m.err﹕ at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
```

It simply states that one of your `String` which you are trying to parse as `double` is `""`.

```
int_list = Double.parseDouble(list.getText().toString());
int_carat = Double.parseDouble(carat.getText().toString());
int_discount = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());
int_converter = Double.parseDouble(converter.getText().toString());
int_discamt = Double.parseDouble(discamt.getText().toString());
```

Make sure your `EditText` have value.

And you can use `String.valueOf(total)` to convert to `String`.

**NOTE:**

- Make sure your `EditText` is not Empty use `ed.getText().toString().equals("")`*(some other validation may be needed this is just an example)* to validate and surround code with try catch when there is possibility of Exception.
- It may be possible you have placed id at wrong `EditText` which remains empty during calculation so please check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to parse an empty String as a double.
You should check with:

```
if (edittext.getText().length > 0)
```